# How can i create a deviations query?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I wanted to write a query that would allow me to calculate deviations by the number of created orders.

Task: the query should look back 7 days and based on this data build a minimum allowable threshold (MAT). If the number of orders for a minimum period of time (5 minutes) is less than MAT, then an alert will be generated.

Features: The number of orders directly affects the time of day and seasonality.

Having searched the Internet, I found information about so-called Poisson distribution, and tried to apply it to the problem, but it didn't work.

In prometheus there are such functions as day_of_week(), avg_over_time() and stddev_over_time.

From what I was able to do:

1. The difference between the number of orders in the last 5 min.
   `sum(delta(my_search_counter{service_name="car.book.v1"}[5m])`
2. Five-minute average time variation over the last 30 minutes with a resolution of 5 minutes
   `avg_over_time(sum(delta(my_search_counter{service_name="car.book.v1"}[5m]))[1w:5m])`
3. Mean square deviation:
   `stddev_over_time(sum(delta(my_search_counter{service_name="car.book.v1"}[5m]))[1w:5m])`

This is where I'm stuck and can't figure out how to build a proper query. Maybe there is another way, simpler, but I haven't found it.

I tried to combine these queries with each other using addition, subtraction and division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what statistics is this, and how adequate this is as a threshold, but here is query you described.

```
sum(increase(my_search_counter{service_name="car.book.v1"}[5m]))
< sum(increase(my_search_counter{service_name="car.book.v1"}[5m] offset 1w))
  - stddev_over_time(sum(increase(my_search_counter{service_name="car.book.v1"}[5m] offset 1w))[1d:5m])
```

It returns value if number of order over last 5 minutes is less then number of orders over same 5 minutes 1 week ago minus standard deviation of orders number over 24 hours presiding current moment 1 week ago.

You might need to play a little with multiplier for stddev part, to get a reasonable percent of alerts.

Comment: Thank you very much,  i separated your query.
1.  I took the second part of your querythat is afte `<`

this will be my threshhold and orders should not be below it.

2. First part of the query: `sum(increase(my_search_counter{service_name="car.book.v1"}[5m])) this is my current value`.

So the only change that i did is from `[1d:5m]` to `[90d:5m]` i think this will give my threshhold more historical info.

If you don't mind can you please explain what did you mean about "to play a little with multiplier for stddev part"?

Comment: @TUR, I meant to write something like `... - 2 * stddev_over_time( ...`, because current threshold might be a bit high, and produce quite a bit of false alerts. OTOH, increasing time range for deviation calculation should have same result.

Comment: Got it. I've already noticed that this threshold does not make it possible to monitor bookings that were made at night, because its values fall into negative.

Comment: @TUR, well, as I said, I'm not really sure in mathematical/statistical part of this idea, but query works as you described. Additionally, since you stretched deviation calculation range over multiple days, it is effectively same for whole day. Consider using my initial suggestion but with multiplier. I believe something like `3` should be enough if I assume use of 3 standard deviations rule correct here.